# Using an excel formula on filtered cells?

Tags: excel, filter, formula, vba

I have the following excel spreadsheet:

[image]

The elevation is increasing in ascending order. The distance is culmulative. Criteria is a separate formula which can be explained here:

[Selecting values in a list based on an interval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22486643/selecting-values-in-a-list-based-on-an-interval/22487034?noredirect=1#22487034)

I want to calculate the slope which is the difference in elevation divided by the difference in distance, but only for the values that have a criteria of "1". Here is a picture showing the spreadsheet filtered and cut where I get the expected values of slope:

[image]

I want to perform this formula on the unfiltered list and to get the desired result in the third image.

[image]

Are there any formula operations in excel that can perform this task? Can it be done in VBA?

Comment: Yes, if can be done with formula. http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/if-HP005209118.aspx

Comment: I agree, but making the if formula use the last cell with that also meets the same criteria is where I am limited. For example B7 = 1, `IF (B7 =1,(A7-A5)/(C7-C5),0)` How would the formula know to subtract from the previous cell with the criteria of 1 which is B5.

Comment: Ok, I understand now.  use something like this - =INDEX(MAX(($D:$D<>"")*(ROW(D:D))),0) to find the most recent row with a value, then use vlookup inside your formula pointed to a column using the row function.  http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/index-function-HP010342608.aspx, http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add 2 helper columns to your table like so:

[image]

Col D tracks the last Elevation that met your criteria.  Similarly, Col E selects the last Distance that met your criteria.  This keep COL F's formula super simple.

Note this is a variation on Alan's comment, but I prefer the legibility and maintainability of the additional columns to the expert level (and lengthy) formula.